# Is it possible to extract div data-app data?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a list of data from drop down box. When I checked the html source, it is nested in this div data-app as below:

```
<div data-app="true" id="app" class="application application--light"></div>
<div class="card" style="height:auto;" data-ripple="false">
<ul data-uid="669" class="list">
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="list__tile list__tile--link" data-ripple="true" style="position: relative;"><div class="list__tile__content">
<div class="list__tile__title">Car 1</div></div></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="list__tile list__tile--link" data-ripple="true"><div class="list__tile__content">
<div class="list__tile__title">Car 2</div></div></a></li>
```

Can anyone advise how I can extract 'Car 1' and 'Car 2' from div class="list__tile__title". Tried using beautifulsoup as below but can't seem to extract anything.

```
for title in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'list__tile__tile'}):
    content_d = title.descendants
    for d in content_d:
        if d.name == 'div' and d.get('class', '') == ['list__tile__title']:
            print(title.text)
```

Is that the right method to use?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks (Some code, url, html example would be cool and helpful)

Comment: Please post the HTML/URL, your code and what do you expect from your code

Comment: Have added the codes and expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can extract data from div using those approch

Using pure JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("div").dataset.app
```

Using jQuery

```
$("div").data("app");
```

Comment: Sorry I dunno javascript. Can use beautifulsoup or selenium to extract these data instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary - Select your element and call the attribut:

```
soup.select_one('#app')['data-app']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
html='''
<div data-app="true" id="app" class="application application--light">text</div>
'''
soup = Soup(html, features="html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('#app')['data-app'])
```

#### Output

```
true
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wanna extract data from a list - have updated my post with more detailed codes. Can advise further on that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. The class name is `list__tile__title` and not `list__tile__tile`.

Here is how I would get the Cars names.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """
<div data-app="true" id="app" class="application application--light"></div>
<div class="card" style="height:auto;" data-ripple="false">
<ul data-uid="669" class="list">
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="list__tile list__tile--link" data-ripple="true" style="position: relative;"><div class="list__tile__content">
<div class="list__tile__title">Car 1</div></div></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" class="list__tile list__tile--link" data-ripple="true"><div class="list__tile__content">
<div class="list__tile__title">Car 2</div></div></a></li>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')
for title in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'list__tile__title'}):
    print(title.text.strip())
```

```
Car 1
Car 2
```

Comment: My output is still 0. I tried similar methods before but cannot get anything:(

Comment: That means the data in that page is being loaded by JavaScript. Use ```selenium```.